# Jquery gallery/lightbox onClick always return "-1"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a gallery of 12 links(images), that when clicked open lightbox and show the clicked image. But when I click the image it always open the last one. When i try to console log index I always get "-1";

```
var image= $('.Gallery div a');
console.log(image.index($(e.target)));
```

Comment: You've only posted half your code. What event are you running under? What element is `e.target`?

Comment: what does `$(e.target).index()` returns ?

Comment: please post ur full code. What is e.target? What event is it?

Comment: it returns  " 0 "

Comment: @OunknownO for any image click?

Comment: @gurvinder372 yes

Comment: can you post your full code or a working fiddle/snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
$('.Gallery div a').click(function(e){
    var index = $(this).index(); //this is the index of your currently clicked element
    //do your rest of logic here
});
```

The above will bind click event to all of `a` tags who has a parent div and which has a parent having `Gallery` class.